# Is <div> before Bootstrap Navbar Fixed Top possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a navbar-fixed-top navigation on my HTML. I'm using this https://github.com/istvan-ujjmeszaros/bootstrap-autohidingnavbar to make the navigation 'smart'.

Now, I want to put a small `<nav>` before the actual `navbar-fixed-top`. But when I put the `<nav>` before the `<navbar-fixed-top>`, it appears after the actual `navbar-fixed-top`.

How can I make it so that it appears before the `navbar-fixed-top`?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx24d8k/

Please help.

Comment: Please make a fiddle.

Comment: @Bonatoc Sorry for the delay. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx24d8k/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kv5drwLr/ - this is two fixed position navbars. If you want to have on static and the other fixed, that's jQuery also because you will need to detect scroll and put it in another location by changing the body's padding

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this, here is one option:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="position:fixed; top:0px">
    <div class="test">lorem ipsm</div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="top:20px">
```

Here's the fix applied to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/hfx24d8k/1/

In your fiddle, the .navbar-fixed-top has position:fixed and top:0px to put it at the top of the screen. So first you need to move it down a bit to allow space for 'lorem ipsm', which you can do with the inline style 'top:20px'.

Next you need to move lorem ispm up. Currently there is 60px padding on the body, so the easiest way to move it up is to make your second nav also be fixed, and move it above the main nav, with the inline styles "position:fixed; top:0px"

Alternatively, you could remove the padding from the body and let the browser position it at the top of the screen. The class .navbar applies position:relative so you need to override this by setting position:static on the lorem ispm nav.

Comment: It doesn't work when the Auto Hiding Nav extension is enabled.  I updated the JS: http://jsfiddle.net/hfx24d8k/2/ - When you scroll down and scroll up, the div before the nav gets hidden.

Comment: You mean "has to get hidden" ? Your additional nav should have the same behaviour ?

Comment: Mehedi, that'll be because your auto-hiding code is resetting the top CSS rule to top:0px ... you're never going to get lorem ipsm at the top unless you make sure that value is bigger than zero... you should maybe patch the JS file and fix this line: `autoHidingNavbar.element.removeClass('navbar-hidden').animate({
      top: 0` and set top to 20

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 <nav style=" 
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0%;
      background-color:red;">
        <div class="test">lorem ipsm</div>
 </nav>
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hfx24d8k/4/